# Minipage width not acurate

Tags: boxes, minipage, width

I have the following document, with several minipages of 12cm width.
Each minipage contains a different number of minipages (with a sum of 12cm for all of them). So every *sub*minipages should fit inside its main minipage, but the more minipages there are, the more they're oversized.
I see no spaces between the minipages, so i don't understand why i have such a behaviour, especialy since the size is in cm and not in 0.X\linewidth.

Thank you for your lights on this.

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{12cm}
\hspace{-1mm}\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{12cm}12\end{minipage}}%
\end{minipage}}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{12cm}
\hspace{-1mm}\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{6cm}6\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{6cm}6\end{minipage}}%
\end{minipage}}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{12cm}
\hspace{-1mm}\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}4\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}4\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}4\end{minipage}}%
\end{minipage}}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{12cm}
\hspace{-1mm}\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}3\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}3\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}3\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}3\end{minipage}}%
\end{minipage}}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{12cm}
\hspace{-1mm}\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}3\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}2\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}3\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}2\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\end{minipage}}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{12cm}
\hspace{-1mm}\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}2\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}3\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}2\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}3\end{minipage}}%
\end{minipage}}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{12cm}
\hspace{-1mm}\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}2\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}2\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}2\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}2\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}2\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}2\end{minipage}}%
\end{minipage}}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{12cm}%
\hspace{-1mm}\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[t]{1cm}1\end{minipage}}%
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

And here is the result :
[image: myscreenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\colorbox` internally uses `\fbox`. Thus there two additonal `\fboxsep` for the left and right side.